# how to scale an integer up and down by multiples of 4... with a twist

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I apologize for the title; I don't even know what I am asking for is really called.

I have two series of numbers (array indices really):

```
{0,1,2,3}
```

AND

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
```

These sets can increase by multiples of 4 (4, 16, 64, 256, etc).

What I am trying to do is figure out how to "scale" an index to its lower multiple, and higher multiple equivalents. There is a catch though. Consider the following crude drawing:

[image]

Each set is to be treated as a square, and when scaling, the result should be in the square region.

Few examples:

- scaling 5 down should result in 0
- scaling 10 down should result in 3
- scaling 11 down should result in 3
- scaling 12 down should result in 2
- scaling 3 down should result in 1

scaling up will never be exact I understand, so for that, I am content with finding the "top left" number. for instance:

- scaling 1 up results in 2
- scaling 2 up results in 8
- scaling 3 up results in 10

I have been at this for a few days now, and every time I find a solution, I realize I only found a solution for a certain "resolution". I just can't seem to figure out the core pattern.

Does this have something to do with quadratics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to $4$-bit binary; take the first and third bits.
$$2\left \lfloor \frac n 8\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n\bmod4}2\right\rfloor$$
To reverse, $$8\left \lfloor \frac n 2\right \rfloor+2(n\bmod2)$$
In the next stage $(64\to16)$, convert to six-bit binary and drop bits $3$ and $6$.
$$4\left \lfloor \frac n {16}\right \rfloor+\left \lfloor \frac {n\bmod8}2 \right \rfloor\\
16\left \lfloor \frac n 4\right \rfloor+2(n\bmod4)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael. Not sure this works 100% though; but maybe I am misunderstanding it. Using the image as an example, I tested your formulas with position 8: I get 2 for the first equation (correct!), but reversing it gives me 0, where I expected to see 8 again. :(

Comment: Quite right, how does my new formula work?

Comment: Caught me mid edit; I am trying again...

Comment: Tried a few numbers and so far looks good. Thanks! I still want to test with a few other numbers with larger sets, but I think this is good (will mark correct when confirmed). Just to ensure I understand though, is it basically: (sqrt(length) * floor(n / (length*2))) + (floor(n mod length)/2)? And for the reverse: (length / 2) * floor(n / sqrt((length / 2) / 4)) + (2 * (n mod (length / 2))?

Comment: @Michael I beautified your post a bit, hope you don't mind. Also, you can use the \bmod command to get better spacing when using mod that way.

Comment: I do think this works. I tried for 59, and I got results 13, and 50, which are correct. I got a bit tripped up testing this, as I was forgetting which formula did what. haha. I think I get the general idea though; I can infer how the constants are arrived (just don't know the markup to make those fancy math symbols). Just basically doing stuff with the sqrt of the set length for the set you are trying to "scale out of" right? Thanks again btw! Can't belive how fast you figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

In general, let's say you have a $2^{n+1} \times 2^{n+1}$ array
indexed according to the scheme you have shown, that is,
if the columns and rows are both numbered $\{0, \ldots, 2^{n+1} - 1\}$,
then the "index" in column $i$ of row $j$ is $k_{n+1}(i,j) = i + j \cdot 2^{n+1}$.
And let's say you want to map the cells of this array to the cells of
a $2^n \times 2^n$ array where the "index" in column $i$ of row $j$ is 
$k_n(i,j) = i + j \cdot 2^n$. 
The first half of your question is, given an index $k_{n+1}$ of a cell in the
first array, you want to know the index $k_n$ of the cell in the second
array to which the first cell is mapped.

Notice that for any index $k_m(i,j)$ of a $2^m \times 2^m$ array,
we can find $i$ and $j$ via these two formulas:
\begin{align}
i &\equiv k_m(i,j)  \pmod{2^m}, \\[6pt]
j &= \left\lfloor \frac{k_m(i,j)}{2^m} \right\rfloor.
\end{align}

Now choose an arbitrary index $k_{n+1}$ from the first array.
This is a number in the range $\{0, \ldots, 4^{n+1} - 1\}$.
If we divide $k_{n+1}$ by $2$, discarding any fractional part,
we end up with a number $k' = \left\lfloor \frac12 k_{n+1} \right\rfloor$
in the range $\{0, \ldots, 2\cdot4^n - 1\}$.
Moreover, 
$k' \equiv k_n \pmod{2^n},$
where $k_n$ is the index we want to find.
So $k' \equiv i \pmod{2^n},$ 
where the cell we are trying to map $k_{n+1}$ to is in column $i$
of the smaller array.

The only reason we cannot use $k'$ as the new index 
is that it "indexes" each row of the smaller array twice.
That is, either
$$\left\lfloor \frac{k'}{2^n} \right\rfloor = 2j
\qquad \text{or} \qquad \left\lfloor \frac{k'}{2^n} \right\rfloor = 2j+1,$$
where the cell we are trying to map $k_{n+1}$ to is in row $j$
of the smaller array.
But if we divide by $2$ again, discarding any fractional part, we get $j$.
Equivalently, we can just divide by $2$ again, discarding the remainder,
and then 
$$j = \left\lfloor \frac12 \left\lfloor \frac{k'}{2^n} \right\rfloor \right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor \frac{k'}{2^{n+1}} \right\rfloor 
 = \left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \tfrac12 k_{n+1} \right\rfloor}{2^{n+1}} \right\rfloor 
 = \left\lfloor \frac{k_{n+1}}{2^{n+2}} \right\rfloor. 
$$
Using $p \bmod q$ to denote the integer $r$ such that $r \equiv p \pmod q$
and $0 \leq r < q$, we can say that the cell indexed by $k_{n+1}$
is mapped to the cell in column $i$, row $j$ of the smaller array where
\begin{align}
i &= \left\lfloor \tfrac12 k_{n+1} \right\rfloor \bmod 2^n, \\[4pt]
j &= \left\lfloor \frac{k_{n+1}}{2^{n+2}} \right\rfloor,
\end{align}
and therefore
$$
k_n = \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k_{n+1}}{2} \right\rfloor \bmod 2^n\right)
      + 2^n \left\lfloor \frac{k_{n+1}}{2^{n+2}} \right\rfloor.
$$

To reverse the mapping, by doubling $k_n$ we get an index of the
larger array that is in the correct column, but at the end of each
row we need to "skip" a row of the larger array.
So the formula is
$$
k_{n+1} = 2 k_n + 2^{n+1} \left\lfloor \frac{k_n}{2^n} \right\rfloor.
$$